# Injecting a jBoss EJB to a JSF 2.0 managed bean running in a tomcat web application

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi, jboss6.x

I have been looking around for some time, and I cannot find a solution, the problem is as follows:

1. I have an EJB3 application deployed in jBoss 6.0, with remote ejb's.
2. I have a web application (JSF 2.0) deployed in Tomcat 6.0.

I don't want to run the tomcat web application in jBoss, its an application
    running under tomcat, and the architecture should remain the same.

I don't want to lookup the EJB manually (I want to inject it) in other words I don't want to do it like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();                                                        
properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");                      
properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");   

Context c = new InitialContext();                                                                
MySB mySB = (MySB) c.lookup("MySB/remote");
```

What I do need is to inject the jBoss EJB's into managed beans in the Tomcat application, for example

```
@EJB(name="MySB/remote")
protected MySB mySB;
```

as if the `MySB/remote` is in the tomcat local JNDI, but in fact its being looked up from the jBoss JNDI behind the scenes.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CDI. Unfortunately CDI support doesn't come with a standard servlet engine like Tomcat, so if you want to deploy a JSF application that leverages CDI annotations you need to get an implementation of the CDI specification. The reference implementation of JSR 299 is known as [Weld](http://seamframework.org/Weld). To install it you need:

1) put `weld-servlet.jar` to the `WEB-INF\lib` folder of your JSF application

2) add following listener definition to your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

3) add in an empty `beans.xml` file alongside the web.xml and faces-config.xml file in the `WEB-INF` folder of the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Finally you need to `@Inject` your EJB in managed beans.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For example if the EJB's are under jboss and its jnp address is jnp://localhost:1099 where should I configure this in tomcat?

Comment: Define the remote EJB as a resource (see http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/resources.html#d0e4373) and then Inject it